# Strategies to send data from a Python program to a C++ program

Tags: python, c++, c, sockets

I need to send some data from a Python program to a C++ program. The current design is such that the C++ program executes the python program in a separate thread. I wish to pass some result from the python program back to the C++ program.

What I have found so far includes:

- Sending over sockets
- Sending via a pipe
- Using a temporary file
- Embedding the python interpreter in the C++ program
- Using boost.python

My data (to be passed back to the C++ program) is essentially a python dictionary, and a few files. (I am sending email details, and the attachments). What strategy should I use?

Is there anything I can do to make my work easier? Or can I improve my program design?

EDIT: Added boost.python to the list of options found.

Comment: Pick a strategy and try it out. If it doesn't work as well as you would like, try another strategy and compare the result. If you run into an error you can't solve or a limitation you can't explain, that might be a better time to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AirThomas Yeah but why go through all that when there are more experienced devs whose suggestions might be able to save you hours of effort sometimes. By the way, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Personally I would go with the python embedded interpreter. Only reason would be that I have more experience using it over pipes and sockets. You wouldn't want to use a temporary file. That would force hard drive access which would be unnecessarily slow.

Comment: @user2970916 Wouldn't it be an overkill just to transfer some data? I went through the docs for embedding an interpreter and didn't want to go via the embedding route because of all the extra code and unfamiliarity. Do you know any good tutorials or packages that make it easier?

Comment: @Richard Those hours of effort are how you get to be an experienced developer in the first place. Compare "I did it this way because the internet told me to" vs. "I did it this way because I tried it other ways and found X, Y, and Z reason to choose this approach." Which developer would you trust more?

Comment: A simple Python dictionary should serialize nicely into JSON (`import json; json.dumps(...).encode('utf8')`), and I'm sure there are C++ libraries for parsing that.  Once you've serialized something to bytes, you can use just about any of these methods to send it.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/

Comment: @AirThomas well said. Guess I was being lazy. Sorry for that.

Comment: @user2970916 I did consider boost.python but again felt intimidated by the complexity of the whole thing. Will add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up altering the the modules such that the C++ part and the Python part can work more or less independently of each other. But if passing data was necessary, I guess I would have gone via the socket route.